# IOS Save Label data

Tags: ios, swift

i know its asked too many times but i tried all examples and still im stuck
i dont know what im gonna do.. im inserting sample code inside still im getting error there is the code without NS is counting the taps end of game i wanna save the tap. when player start the game i wanna load last value of tap also i need help for clear taps..

```
//Score Counting button
var count : Int = 0
@IBAction func ButtonA(sender: AnyObject) {
//Score counting
    count += 1
    Score.text = String(count) }

//objects
@IBOutlet weak var Score: UILabel! //this is the taps numbers
@IBOutlet weak var ScoreInfo: UITextField!
```

im a begginer pls dont hit hard :)

Comment: Since you are a beginner consider the naming convention that variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.  If this code throws an error you might have forgotten to connect the label to the outlet in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific with your problem? Part of getting help is asking the right question. Some things that come to mind:

1. Are your @IB Outlets and Action properly connected to their components in the storyboard?
2. When you say "the player start the game", does that mean you want the data to persist on each app launch? If so, then you will need to use some type of database such as CoreData or Realm to persist your data. If this isn't the case, then you should be fine as `count` will persist in whatever ViewController is holding it.
3. Your object variable names look like they're subclassing the UILAbel and UITextfield classes. I recommend you camel case (i.e. score, scoreInfo, buttonA) your variable names.
4. Also not sure what you're trying to use the textfield for. Label will be sufficient like you've done already.

Comment: 1)Yes count is working perfectly but when you restart app it's starting 0 again
2) first lunch probably will be 0 so when game over I want that last tap count number to save
3)I don't understand that :(
4) so this mean also I can use label for "you tapped x times" text ? Cuz I'm using text field as a info what's the numbers for 
Thanks for quick response

Comment: 1) Right, it's starting 0 again because you need to save the data somewhere. Just because the variable is created at launch doesn't mean it will stay when you restart the app. That's what databases are for. 

3) Rename your variable with the first word lower case and 2nd word Upper case. Some examples: variableName, camelCase, buttonA, scoreInfo.

4) Oh if they both have a purpose then that's fine.

Comment: so how can i do that ?

Comment: I recommend you read some tutorials or watch some videos on using Realm. https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: ill thank you but i don't like to change button names because i have 4683 different buttons :( so each buttons showing the counts but issue i cannot save :D

Comment: now i have billion questions :)

so i did this in realm but i dont know how to i call taps 

class Score: Object {
 Dynamic var taps = ""
}

Let myScore = Score()
myScore.taps = "how can i get the score here :)'
print("taps : \(myScore.taps)")

let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
 realm.add(myScore)
}

score.count

Answer (score 0):

ok i fix my problem spacial thanks for ideas :) now i can save* score i can add* score the high score and i can load latest* (*** this is important for me ) score in the game doesnt matter app is close or device restart oh and without Realm :)

there is code

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var HighscoreLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ScoreLbl: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Reset: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Counter: UIButton!

var Score = 0
var Highscore = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscorekey") != nil){
      Highscore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscorekey") as! NSInteger!
        HighscoreLbl.text = NSString(format: "Highscore : %i", Highscore) as String
    }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func ResetAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    Score = 0
    ScoreLbl.text = NSString(format: "Score : %i", Score) as String

    HighscoreLbl.text = NSString(format: "Highscore: %i", Highscore) as String


}

@IBAction func CounterAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Score Start
    Score += 1
    ScoreLbl.text = NSString(format: "Score : %i", Score) as String
    if (Score > Highscore){
        Highscore = Score
        HighscoreLbl.text = NSString(format: "Highscore: %i", Highscore) as String
    }
    else {
    Score += Highscore
        HighscoreLbl.text = NSString(format: "Highscore: %i", Highscore) as String

    }

    let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    HighscoreDefault.setValue(Highscore, forKey: "Highscorekey")
    HighscoreDefault.synchronize()

    //Score End
}
```

}